# Geocoding an address with Google Maps API

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps

Is there a method for retrieving the Latitude and a Longitude of a specific address using Google Maps API?

I'm trying to build a web page where you can put an address in a textbox then the lat and the long will be automatically calulated.

like this page : http://universimmedia.pagesperso-orange.fr/geo/loc.htm

Comment: please read this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: The example in the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 documentation does that](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple) - [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very basic example:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var a = "your address here";

geocoder.geocode({ 'address' : a}, function(results, status) {
  var c = results[0].geometry.location;
  var latitude = c.lat();
  var longitude = c.lng();        
});
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a HTTPS GET request to

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=YOUR+ADDRESS

Google Geocoding API is subject to API throttling. There's a limit to how many requests you can fire in a minute. If you cross the limit, your IP will be banned for a few seconds. Better check from the official site.

Answer (score 0):

The process you are looking for is called "geocoding" and is documented very well here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/